# method implemented in abstract class, but appears in interface

Tags: java, oop

I'm learning abstract classes vs interfaces at the moment and trying to figure out situations where to use one over the other. I'm having trouble figuring out this example at the moment:

```
public interface Face {
    public void test();
}

public abstract class Tract {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("over here");
    }
}

public class Thing extends Tract implements Face {
    public void test() {
        // what should print out?
    }

}
```

Here, the test() function is implemented in the abstract class. If you don't implement it in the subclass, would it call the abstract class' method and print out "over here"? Does the interface accept implementations from an ancestor class or do you have to implement it in the subclass, therefore overriding the abstract class implementation?

Comment: *or do you have to implement it in the subclass* - why don't you try it and see

Comment: The downvote tooltip says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." That seems reasonable to me, as the obvious research effort is "trying it to see" along with "searching for similar questions".

Comment: No evidence of actually trying, or any research, pushes questions like this just over the line between 'good question' and 'homework dump'.  Would it have killed the OP to just try it, and then ask why?

Answer (score 1):

All the interface cares about is that the class has implemented a method called `test()` that returns `void`.  It does not matter whether the method is implemented in the class directly or in any ancestor (parent) class.

In your case, the `Thing` class has inherited its definition of `test()` from `Tract`, and therefore implements the `Face` interface without you having to provide a definition explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

In the class "Tract" you have given an implementation for the method coming from the interface. Also you override it in "Thing" class so when calling this method on a Thing instance then this version(Thing version) is going to be called.

Answer (score 0):

All java methods are virtual.
lets consider little bit modified code,
I hope, you will get the idea:

```
public interface Face {
    public void test();
}

public abstract class Tract {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Tract here");
    }
}

public class Thing extends Tract implements Face {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Thing here");
    }
}

public class Thing2 extends Tract implements Face {
}
```

lets go to output:

```
Tract tr = new Tract();
tr.test();
```

will not compile because you can't instantiate abstract class.

```
Thing th = new Thing();
th.test();
```

will print "Thing here"

```
Thing2 th2 = new Thing2();
th2.test();
```

will print "Tract here",

because you not overwritten the test() method in abstract class.
Main idea of this approach - you can abstract implementation in the future use

```
class C {
void print(Face face) {
    face.test();
  }
}
new C(new Thing()).print();
```

will print "Thing here";

```
new C(new Thing2()).print();
```

will print "Tract here";
You can hide different implementations
But this is not main idea of abstract classes.
main idea abstract classes are:

```
public interface Face {
    public void test();
}

public abstract class Abstract {
    abstract public void test();
}

public class Thing1 extends Abstract implements Face {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Thing1 here");
    }
}

public class Thing2 extends Abstract implements Face {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Thing2 here");
    }
}
```

main idea - you can declare method without implementation

```
new C(new Thing1()).print();
```

will print "Thing1 here";

```
new C(new Thing2()).print();
```

will print "Thing2 here";
main idea - you declare the method in abstract class, that you MUST override to compile code.
I hope, this is enough explained answer.